# Typescript 2.0 Namespaces file is not a module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using TypeScript 2.1.0 and VS Code 1.3 and I'm trying to get used to the module/namespace system in TypeScript 2. I have a file `validators.ts`

```
namespace Validator{
  export interface String{
    isValid(s:string):boolean;
  }
}
declare module 'validator'{
  export = Validator;
}
```

And when I try to use it like 
`import  {Validator} from "../validators/validators";`

I get the error `validators.ts is not a module`.
I'm installing my external types with `npm i @types/myTypes` and after installing bluebird and copying its structure I'm still seeing this error.  Is this a VS Code bug, or a me bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's much simpler:

```
export namespace Validator{
  export interface String{
    isValid(s:string):boolean;
  }
}
```

You should use `declare module` only when writing type definitions for external libraries. For your own TypeScript code, use regular ES6 style `import` and `export` syntax.

Comment: how can I properly import this interface? `import {String} from "../validators/validators"; as no exported member String`

if I do `import * as S from "../validators/validators";` I don't see the String interface available through intellisense.

Comment: If you don't need the wrapping `Validator` namespace, just get rid of it by removing the first and last line from my code snippet.

Comment: I'm most interested in exporting multiple interfaces in the same file.  is there a good way to export multiple interfaces from the same file?

Comment: Sure, just add multiple exports in the same file! `export interface A {...} export interface B {...}` You don't really need namespaces when you're going to use ES6 modules.

Comment: thanks for the heads up.  I'm unsure when VS Code has a bug and when I've gotten the wrong TypeScript syntax.  +1

Comment: Yes, but there are cases when a namespace is needed - So the question remains, what is the syntax for importing the namespace?

Comment: @redevill With the example in this answer: `import {Validator} from './validator'`;` Then you can use it as: `let myValidator: Validator.String;`